# Excel condition on cell for valid password

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is Excel question,

I'm creating a template for importing users in bulk to the system,
one of the columns requires to input password,

I would like to create a condition on the [password] cell, in order to indicate to the person that input the details that the password is valid

those are the conditions:

```
Passwords must be between 8 and 20 characters. 
Must contain one lower & uppercase letter, 
and one non-alpha character (a number or a symbol.)
```

is it possible?

Comment: Do you require a formula, or is the use of VBA allowed? The latter would make things a whole lot easier.

Comment: i understand it will be easier but VBA is not allowed :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break it down into stages:

> Passwords must be between 8 and 20 characters.

So, this means that for the value in cell `A1`, we want where `LEN(A1)` is `>=8` and `<=20`.  There are a couple of ways to do this, I'll go with `MEDIAN(8, LEN(A1), 20)=LEN(A1)` as a simple one.

> Must contain one lower & uppercase letter

Now, if you just run a check on `UPPER(A1)=LOWER(A1)` then you see that a normal check ignores Case...  But, an `EXACT` comparison preserves case!  So, `EXACT(A1,UPPER(A1))` will be `TRUE` if all the letters in cell `A1` are capital.  We want this to be `FALSE` for both the `UPPER` and `LOWER` checks: `NOT(OR(EXACT(A1,UPPER(A1)),EXACT(A1,LOWER(A1))))`

> and one non-alpha character (a number or a symbol.)

This is the tricky one.  I'm going to recommend using `SUMPRODUCT` to force an array-formula calculation of an `AGGREGATE` to `FIND` one of a specific list of symbols.  For example, if you were looking for any of `"!", "£" or "$"` then this code would return `TRUE` if they were present, or `FALSE` if they were not:  `IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND({"!","£","$"},A1),1)),0)>0`

If you can use a hidden sheet, you can put your "symbols" into a column to check, for example: `IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND(SuperHiddenSheet!$A$1:$A$50,1)),0)>0`

Now, just stick your 3 conditions into an `AND`, and you have your test:

```
=AND(MEDIAN(8, LEN(A1), 20)=LEN(A1), NOT(OR(EXACT(A1,UPPER(A1)),EXACT(A1,LOWER(A1)))), IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND({"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","!","£","$","%","^","&","(",")","@","'","~","#","\","/","|","<",">","[","]","{","}","_","-","+","="},A1),1)),0)>0)
```

(I have left "*" out of the "special character" list)

Comment: The "easy" way to count special characters, is to count digits+alpha, then subtract from overall length.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to find any symbol in formulas, VBA might work better. Please check if this is good enough for you.

```
=IF(AND(NOT(EXACT(UPPER(A1);A1));NOT(EXACT(LOWER(A1);A1));LEN(A1)<=20;LEN(A1)>=8;OR(COUNT(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A1))>0;(COUNT(FIND({"`";"~";"!";"@";"#";"$";"%";"^";"&";"*";"(";")";"_";"-";"+";"=";"{";"}";"[";"]";"\";"|";":";";";"""";"'";"<";">";",";".";"?";"/"};A1)))>0));"VALID";"INVALID")
```